# Getting an error - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Tags: php, mysql, performance, out-of-memory

I have script where I am sending bunch of emails at a time. But I am getting an error:

> The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size.

I did google and got many suggestions. Mostly said increase size of **innodb_buffer_pool_size**. I tried that as well but still not working for me.

Comment: Can you show us this script?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more details, all I can say is to elaborate on the recommendation:  Increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* RAM.  Set it in the `my.cnf` file.